# How can I tell, if window is in a jQuery set?

Tags: jquery, window, filtering

I want my jQuery plugin to behave differently, when called on a `$(window)` selection. How can I check, if `window` is in the set? My tries so far:

```
>>> $(window) == $(window)
false
>>> $(window).is(window)
false
>>> $(window).filter(window).length
0
```

(Those all work fine for `document`, by the way.) Of course I can always inspect `this[0]`, but there are edge cases like `$('a').add(window)` that are not catered by this approach.

I can also filter via function:

```
>>> $(window).filter(function() { return this === window; }).length
1
```

but I was hoping for a bit more 'jQuery-ish' or generic approach.

Comment: how can `$(window) == $(window)
` return `false`?

Comment: No idea. I think it has to do with window being special. In other cases the jQuery lib caches selections (and hence returns the same object), but I seem to remember, that `window` is handled differently.

Comment: @undefined They are 2 different wrappers, that is why. Objects are equal,if they are references to *same* object.

Comment: That's the place in the code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L185 jQuery generates a new Array-like object every time, `$(window)` is called.

Comment: @undefined I guess they are two different jQuery instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and pass it the `window` object. It will return `-1` if the `window` object is not part of the set, or its zero-based index within the set otherwise:

```
>>> $(window).index(window) >= 0
true

>>> $("a").add(window).index(window) >= 0
true

>>> $("a").index(window) >= 0
false
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, only the `$(window).parent()` & `$(document).parent()` return an empty array.
Maybe you can use something like

```
var test = window
  //undefined
$(test).parent().length == 0 && !$(test).is(document)
  //true
test = document
  //#document
$(test).parent().length == 0 && !$(test).is(document)
  //false
```

Comment: In my case, that works perfectly (`$([window, document]).parent().length != $([window, document]).length`). +1. I'm accepting +Frédéric Hamidi's answer, because it's closer to the actual question (that is, it would give a false positive for `$(document)`).

Answer (score 1):

The `.is($(window))` works:

```
         $(window).is($(window))​    //true
$('a').add(window).is($(window))   //true
```

Comment: Nice solution. I'm accepting +Frédéric Hamidi's answer, because it gets along without another jQuery instance being created, but apart from that, this looks good, too. Thanks!