# js how to get selector from $(document) & $(window)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, selector, document

I want to know how to get selector from $(document) & $(window)?

```
el = $(document);

alert(el.selector); // return nothing, I want to output -> document

el = $(window);

alert(el.selector); // return nothing, I want to output -> window
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: the `selector` property is for internal use only and should only be used for debugging, if that.

Comment: do you mean `alert(el.context);`? Selectors are always strings, and you're not passing any selectors to the jQuery function.

Comment: If you could elaborate a little on *why* you need to do this, you may get some helpful advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no selector value when you instantiate a jQuery object from a DOM element or something like `window`.

If you just want to know if a jQuery object wraps `document` or `window`, do this:

```
if (theObject.length === 1 && theObject[0] === document) {
  // it's $(document) ...
}
```

In fact you can also do this:

```
if (theObject.is(document)) {
```

or

```
if (theObject.is(window))
```

The `.is()` function also works if you want to test for specific DOM elements too.

Comment: I tried, it worked with .is(document), but not worked with .is(window)

Comment: @Till hmm ... you're right; that's bizarre.  I don't know why that wouldn't work, unless it's specifically intended to only work for parts of the DOM (and `window` isn't really part of the DOM).  I'll look at the jQuery source code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017019/how-can-i-tell-if-window-is-in-a-jquery-set

Comment: I also tried something on that post, didnt work for window also

Comment: Also note that `is()` will return true as long as at least 1 of the wrapped elements matches the selector. So `$(document).add('body').is(document)` is true.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes - I think that checking for `length` is good too.  Of course, I'm really not sure I understand the purpose of this.

Comment: Yeah, I don't either. The first solution using array notation is what I'd use so +1

Comment: @Till yes the jQuery code checks to see if a non-string has a "nodeType" property, which means that `$(window).is(window)` works if you've got a global variable called "nodeType" that's `true` :-) (I'm not suggesting doing that!)

Comment: Rofl, that is a good one @Pointy. Demo for anyone that wants to see it with your own eyes: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KzwF4/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no selector, so there's nothing to get. You're passing a node.

A *"selector"* is a string of text that conforms to the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/), which is the same API used by CSS. In JavaScript, the selectors are a subset of the API, or if using jQuery, there are proprietary extensions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no selector. `jQuery` is wrapping those `DOM` element references in a `jQuery` object.

For more information see [jQuery source `init`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L80)